# Redis - difference between storing dictionary with hmset and set

Tags: python, redis

I just got started to Redis, and i want to use it to store temporary data about users for an application i'm creating, so basically for each user there is a record, the name of the user is the key and the value is a dictionary with some data and i need to expire each record after some time, in this case 1 minute:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import redis
import json

r = redis.Redis()

r.setex(
   "user_1",
   timedelta(minutes=1),
   value="{'messages': 0, 'channel': xx}"
)

r.setex(
   "user_2",
   timedelta(minutes=1),
   value="{'messages': 0, 'channel': xy}"
)


o = r.get("user_2")

print(o.decode("utf-8"))
```

So, if i understood Redis correctly, i'm creating a series of dictionaries like: `{"user_1": "{'messages': 0, 'channel': xx}"}` and so on. My question is: what difference is there between what i'm doing and using `hmset`? I noticed that in order to store dictionaries, the general advice is to use `hmset`, but what i did works, so what difference is there?

Comment: My understanding is that it's just a more efficient way to work with dictionaries.  You can change the value of an individual key whereas with set you are replacing the value of the entire dict even if only one key in the dict needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is clear now, just wanted to make sure i was not doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically store data in a hash map, if you wanted to access individual fields of your records.

For example:

```
redis>  HSET user1 messages "0" channel "xx"

(integer) 1

redis>  HSET user2 messages "0" channel "xx2"

(integer) 1

redis>  HMGET user1 channel

1) "xx2"
```

On the other hand, right now to access the channel for user1 you'd need to pull down the whole record and then access the field (I can't remember if you need to use json.loads to convert it back to a dict in Python).